# How to use Assuming and If together?

Tags: assumptions, conditional

I would like to compare variables `t` and `u` and print either `Yes` or `No` depending one which is larger.

My code is simply the following:

```
Assuming[t < u, If[t - u < 0, Print[Yes], Print[No]]]
```

Since `t < u` is assumed, `t - u < 0` holds. So I should get `Yes`. But what I get is a repetition of `If` term. That is,

```
If[t - u < 0, Print[Yes], Print[No]]
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: If[t < u, Print[Yes], Print[No]]

Comment: @paw, I get the same result.

Comment: You need a `Simplify` (`Assuming[t < u, Simplify[If[t - u < 0, Print[Yes], Print[No]]]]`) otherwise the `Assumpition` has no effect.

Comment: `If` has no `Assumptions` option.

Comment: @Karsten, It worked! Thank you so much! But one question: Why do I have to simplify it which is already very simple? Do I have to always do this in this case regardless whether If clause is simple or not?

Comment: @Karsten, I see. `If` has no `Assumptions` options, so I have to always use `Simplify`.... Thank you so much!

Comment: [`Assuming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html?q=Assuming) only has an effect on an expression, if the expression has the option `Assumptions`, like `Simplify` has.

Comment: @Karsten, got it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ppp I noticed you never accepted any answer to your previous questions. Maybe you would get more responses if you checked "Accept" on some of the earlier answers that you apparently liked.

Comment: @Jens Just figured out! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need to use here is [`Refine`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Refine.html):

```
Refine[If[t - u < 0, Print[Yes], Print[No]], t < u]

Yes
```

Ad if you need to work with `$Assumptions` as well, then you could do this:

```
$Assumptions = t < u;

Refine[If[t - u < 0, Print[Yes], Print[No]], $Assumptions]

Yes
```

The last line is also the way it would look if you were to wrap your `If` statement in `Assuming`. However, since `$Assumptions` is also used by default, you can simply do this:

```
Assuming[t < u, Refine[If[t - u < 0, Print[Yes], Print[No]]]]

Yes
```

Comment: This is very helpful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: what about in case of multiple assumptions? Can I do add them with `&&`?

Comment: @ppp Yes, the docs have many examples.