# Assuming and Conjugate do not work as expected

Tags: complex, assumptions

I tried to work with Conjugates in Mathematica and it did not produce my desired result. I learned about assumptions and figured they're my way to go.
This is the code:

```
Assuming[Element[a, Reals] && Element[e, Reals] && Element[m, Reals] && 
Element[r, Reals] && e > 0 && r > 0 && m > 0, Conjugate[(a E^(-I Sqrt[2] Sqrt[e m] r))/r]]
```

However, this is the output:

> ```
> (E^(I Sqrt[2] Conjugate[Sqrt[e m] r]) Conjugate[a])/Conjugate[r]
> ```

Since all variables are real and positive, I'd expect only the sign in the exponent to flip. Why does it still want to conjugate real positive variables?

Comment: Documentation for `Assuming` states clearly that it automates passing its argument to `$Assumptions`, to be used by functions that have the `Assumptions` option. `Conjugate` is not such a function. But `Simplify` is such a function so you might try wrapping that around the expression to be altered.

Comment: Also see [this prior MSE thread](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59023/how-to-use-assuming-and-if-together) or [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23165/inequalities-with-assumptions-and-constraints)

Comment: This is similar to several other question - the closest I could find is this:  [Replacements/Substitutions in Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14994/replacements-substitutions-in-mathematica)

Comment: @infinitezero, you might be interested in this "cheat sheet" I made for my complex analysis students: https://github.com/rljacobson/Complex-Analysis-with-Computer-Algebra.